# Checking if keyword in one table is within a string in another table using R

Tags: r, database, loops, apply, mapply

I've been trying to solve this issue with mapply, but I believe I will have to use several nested applies to make this work, and it has gotten real confusing.

The problem is as follows:

Dataframe one contains around 400 keywords. These fall into roughly 15 categories.
Dataframe two contains a string description field, and 15 additional columns, each named to correspond to the categories mentioned in dataframe one. This has millions of rows.

If a keyword from dataframe 1 exists in the string field in dataframe 2, the category in which the keyword exists should be flagged in dataframe 2.

What I want should look something like this:

```
    > #Dataframe1 df1
    >> keyword    category
    >> cat        A
    >> dog        A
    >> pig        A
    >> crow       B
    >> pigeon     B
    >> hawk       B
    >> catfish    C
    >> carp       C
    >> ...
    >>
    > #Dataframe2 df2
    >> description    A    B    C    ....
    >> false cat      1    0    0    ....
    >> smiling pig    1    0    0    ....
    >> shady pigeon   0    1    0    ....
    >> dogged dog     2    0    0    ....
    >> sad catfish    0    0    1    ....
    >> hawkward carp  0    1    1    ....
    >> ....
```

I tried to use mapply to get this to work but it fails, giving me the error "longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter". It also computes this only for the first string in df2. I haven't proceeded beyond this stage, i.e. attempting to get category flags.

```
    > mapply(grepl, pattern = df1$keyword, x = df2$description)
```

Could anyone be of help? I thank you very much. I am new to R so it would also help if someone could mention some 'thumb rules' for turning loops into apply functions. I cannot afford to use loops to solve this as it would take way too much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the implementation, counting the number of matches per category needs `k x d` comparisons, where `k` is the number of keywords and `d` the number of descriptions.

There are a few tricks to make solve this problem fast and without a lot of memory:

- Use vectorized operations. These can be performed a lot quicker than use for loops. Note that lapply, mapply or vapply are just shorthand for for loops. I parallelize (see next) over the keywords such that the vectorization can be over the descriptions which is the largest dimension.
- Use parallelization. Optimally using your multiple cores speeds up the proces at the cost of an increase in memory (since every core needs its own copy).

Example:

```
keywords            <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(400, 2)
categories          <- letters[1:15]
keyword_categories  <- sample(categories, 400, TRUE)
descriptions        <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(3e6, 20)

keyword_occurance <- function(word, list_of_descriptions) {
  description_keywords   <- str_detect(list_of_descriptions, word)
}

category_occurance <- function(category, mat) {
  rowSums(mat[,keyword_categories == category])
}

list_keywords <- mclapply(keywords, keyword_occurance, descriptions, mc.cores = 8)
df_keywords   <- do.call(cbind, list_keywords)
list_categories <- mclapply(categories, category_occurance, df_keywords, mc.cores = 8)
df_categories <- do.call(cbind, list_categories)
```

With my computer this takes 140 seconds and 14GB RAM to match 400 keywords in 15 categories to 3 million descriptions.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works as well, although I haven't tried it on the large dataset. I'm curious as to how the memory considerations work. With respect to [ikop](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7760498/ikop)'s answer above, which creates a really large list in the interim, would your solution which creates a large data frame be more or less memory intensive?

Comment: I have edited my answer to make both a fast and memory efficient implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the error `'mc.cores' > 1 is not supported on Windows`. Is there any workaround? You were right, the apply functions are far too slow for larger datasets.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more elegant way to do this but this is what I came up with:

```
## Your sample data:
df1 <- structure(list(keyword = c("cat", "dog", "pig", "crow", "pigeon", "hawk", "catfish", "carp"), 
    category = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C")), 
    .Names = c("keyword", "category"), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-8L))
df2 <- structure(list(description = structure(c(2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L,3L),
    .Label = c("dogged dog", "false cat", "hawkward carp", "sad catfish", "shady pigeon", "smiling pig"), class = "factor")), 
    .Names = "description", row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

## Load packages:
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

## For each entry in df2$description count how many times each keyword
## is contained in it:
outList <- lapply(df2$description, function(description){
        outDf <- data.frame(description = description,
                value = vapply(stringr::str_extract_all(description, df1$keyword), 
                        length, numeric(1)), category = df1$category) 
    })

## Combine to one long data frame and aggregate by category:
outLongDf<- do.call('rbind', outList) %>%
    group_by(description, category) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(value = sum(value))

## Reshape from long to wide format:
outWideDf <- tidyr::spread(data = outLongDf, key = category,
    value = value)

outWideDf
# Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
# Groups: description [6]
# 
#     description     A     B     C
# *        <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    dogged dog     2     0     0
# 2     false cat     1     0     0
# 3 hawkward carp     0     1     1
# 4   sad catfish     1     0     1
# 5  shady pigeon     1     1     0
# 6   smiling pig     1     0     0
```

This approach, however also catches the "pig" in "pigeon" and the "cat" in "catfish". I don't know if this is what you want, though.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much. Yes, I didn't want the "cat" in "catfish" to be found but that is only secondary.

Comment: Unfortunately, it turns out this method is far too slow for the larger dataset in mind.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a so-called document-term-matrix (or dtm in short), which stems from NLP (Natural Language Processing). There are many options available. I prefer `text2vec`. This package is blazingly fast (I wouldn't be surprised if it would outperform the other solutions here by a large magnitude) especially in combination with `tokenizers`.

In your case the code would look something like this:

```
# Create the data
df1 <- structure(list(keyword = c("cat", "dog", "pig", "crow", "pigeon", "hawk", "catfish", "carp"), 
                      category = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C")), 
                 .Names = c("keyword", "category"), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-8L))
df2 <- structure(list(description = structure(c(2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L,3L),
                                              .Label = c("dogged dog", "false cat", "hawkward carp", "sad catfish", "shady pigeon", "smiling pig"), class = "factor")), 
                 .Names = "description", row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

# load the libraries
library(text2vec) # to create the dtm
library(tokenizers) # to help creating the dtm
library(reshape2) # to reshape the data from wide to long

# 1. create the vocabulary from the keywords
vocabulary <- vocab_vectorizer(create_vocabulary(itoken(df1$keyword)))

# 2. create the dtm
dtm <- create_dtm(itoken(as.character(df2$description)), vocabulary)

# 3. convert the sparse-matrix to a data.frame
dtm_df <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(dtm))
dtm_df$description <- df2$description

# 4. melt to long format
df_result <- melt(dtm_df, id.vars = "description", variable.name = "keyword")
df_result <- df_result[df_result$value == 1, ]

# 5. combine the data, i.e., add category
df_final <- merge(df_result, df1, by = "keyword")
# keyword   description value category
# 1    carp hawkward carp     1        C
# 2     cat     false cat     1        A
# 3 catfish   sad catfish     1        C
# 4     dog    dogged dog     1        A
# 5     pig   smiling pig     1        A
# 6  pigeon  shady pigeon     1        B
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm interested in the potential speed benefits. What if a string has multiple keywords. Will this solution work to identify every one of them and let me provide a flag for every one? For example, "dogs catching carp" should set a value 2 for A and a value 1 for C.

Comment: Should work as well. The DTM lists all document (text) and term (vocabulary) relationships. Thus "dogs catching carp" would list "dogs" and "carp"  (given they are both in the vocabulary/term).
If you have large datasets, you might want to clean the dtm before converting to a data.frame.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will create an entirely new row everytime there's a match. Do you have a workaround for this?

In fact, there's an issue with finding all of the strings. It attempts to make the number of rows equal to the number of keywords. This is the same issue I had with mapply.

Comment: Thats the difference between long and wide format, right? If you take ikop's last code-block to gather the data again `tidyr::spread(data = df_final, key = category, value=value)`. Now you might want to replace the NAs with zeros.

Comment: You're right! It works. My bad. Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: `Duplicate identifiers for rows (70, 94, 95)....` and so on is the error I get for the larger dataset. This is because, oftentimes, the descriptions can be the same in different (but not corresponding to the same user). The same occurs when using the description as a key, as categories are duplicated in that case. I've tried using spread() with a new, unique key for every field but it doesn't work. Also, I may be mistaken, but all of the keywords in the string are not found. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using unique entries for the vocabulary?